# Word for "takes over" in context of thought

Tags: single-word-requests

I'd like to know a word meaning "take over" when it comes to one's mind.

> Tonight, a dream that's not hers **takes over** her mind in a way that she can't push it to the background.

Comment: ***Occupy:***  http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/occupy

Answer (score 1):

I'm tempted to add "[commandeer](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commandeer/)" and "[hijack](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hijack/)" to Josh61's list in case you're looking for a more active sense of "take over."

While "occupy" elicits the image of taking over and sitting there, "commandeer" and "hijack" suggest taking over and moving in another direction.

Comment: Nice answer, but maybe you can provide or link to (reputable) dictionary definitions? It might attract more votes.